# How to build a classmap at runtime for nested properties

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Suppose I have data structures like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{
   public Bar A {get;set;}
   public Bar B {get;set;}
   public int C {get;set;}
}
public class Bar
{
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

and a CSV file with the contents

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
0,1,2
3,4,5
```

I would like to now map `Column1` to `A.Value` and `Column2` to `B.Value` and `Column3` to `C`.
I'm restricted to runtime mapping.
For `Column3` -> `C`, I can write

```cs
var type = typeof(Foo);
var customMap = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DefaultClassMap<>).MakeGenericType(type)) as ClassMap;
customMap.Map(type, type.GetProperty("C")).Name("Column3");
csv_reader.Context.RegisterClassMap(customMap);
```

How can I map columns 1 and 2?

Comment: The problem here is not the nested classes - that is doable, it is `Bar` being reused so you cant map `Bar.Value` to 2 different columns (even though it is 2 separate instances of `Bar`). If you could have 2 different classes I think this is possible (eg `BarA` and `BarB`).

Comment: That is _not_ possible. I don't control what type the user puts in, so two `Bar`s are very much a reality.

Comment: I think you're limited to [reading by hand](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/) then

Comment: Thanks. I think that means I should ask for that to become a feature. Doesn't sound impossible to me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can do this.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("Column1,Column2,Column3\r\n");
    s.Append("0,1,2\r\n");
    s.Append("3,4,5\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var fooType = typeof(Foo);
        var barType = typeof(Bar);
        
        var fooMapType = typeof(DefaultClassMap<>).MakeGenericType(fooType);
        var barMapType = typeof(DefaultClassMap<>).MakeGenericType(barType);
        
        var map = (ClassMap)ObjectResolver.Current.Resolve(fooMapType);
        map.Map(fooType, fooType.GetProperty("C")).Name("Column3");
        map.References(barMapType, fooType.GetProperty("A")).Data.Mapping.Map(barType, barType.GetProperty("Value")).Name("Column1");
        map.References(barMapType, fooType.GetProperty("B")).Data.Mapping.Map(barType, barType.GetProperty("Value")).Name("Column2");

        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

private class Foo
{
    public Bar A { get; set; }
    public Bar B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking into ways to make this easier for people that want to create maps at runtime.